# PetaPoco fetch only retrieves totalCount but not items

Tags: petapoco

Using PetaPoco, I am running a fetch similar to this:

```
var result=db.Page<article>(1, 20, // <-- page number and items per page
    "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category=@0 ORDER BY date_posted DESC", "coolstuff");
```

where article is defined as

```
public class article
{
  public long article_id { get; set; }
  public string title { get; set; }
  public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
  public bool draft { get; set; }
  public string content { get; set; }
}
```

But while result.TotalItems shows the correct number, result.Items does not contain anyting.  I have also tried to decorate the definition of class article with

```
[PetaPoco.TableName("articles")]
[PetaPoco.PrimaryKey("article_id")]
```

and explicit column mapping

```
[PetaPoco.Column]
```

but result has always been the same.  Is there a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run it through debug and found the exact query that gets executed against the db? You can do this manually or use PetaPoco.Glimpse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the page number starts from 1 and not 0. Its possible that in your code that you did not show here has that bug.